# Livecycle Server Accessing Issues

Tags: c#, adobe, livecycle, livecycle-designer

I have a Livecycle application running on a remote computer. In my C# program, I am trying to access Livecycle server, however I have some connection issues on this subject. Should I first connect to the remote machine that Livecycle is running on and then set the credentials for the Livecycle server ? Also, should I connect to this remote machine through socket programming? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about what you mean with connecting. Are you trying to invoke a LiveCycle process for example?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that when you say "Livecycle Server", you mean "Livecycle Services".

ALC services are exposed through various channels, perhaps the most common used by customers is SOAP (Web Services).

By default, each SOAP petition must contain the user credentials that are performed (user / password):

SOAP properties (to setup on client side) sample:

```
Properties ConnectionProps = new Properties();
ConnectionProps.setProperty(ServiceClientFactoryProperties.DSC_DEFAULT_SOAP_ENDPOINT, "http://localhost:8080");
ConnectionProps.setProperty(ServiceClientFactoryProperties.DSC_TRANSPORT_PROTOCOL,ServiceClientFactoryProperties.DSC_SOAP_PROTOCOL);          
ConnectionProps.setProperty(ServiceClientFactoryProperties.DSC_SERVER_TYPE, "JBoss");
ConnectionProps.setProperty(ServiceClientFactoryProperties.DSC_CREDENTIAL_USERNAME, "changeit");
ConnectionProps.setProperty(ServiceClientFactoryProperties.DSC_CREDENTIAL_PASSWORD, "changeit");
```

The following link explains this in detail and more examples:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/programLC/help/index.htm?content=000501.html

The way in which different properties are assigned may vary depending on the language, or framework of web services (axis, cxf ...), but the fact is that either way you have to include the information in the request, otherwise will be rejected by the server.

Comment: The above link no longer works